# Using !! in if statements

Tags: javascript

I have come across code in a web app where it uses !!, I was told that this enforces a check for true or false instead of truthy or falsy. Is this correct?

```
if (!!this._currentItemIndex) {
      this._findItemByCurrentIndex();
}
```

I have been having trouble finding any resources online to explain this.

Comment: Its correct.  The use of !! (or "bang bang") just forces the value to the inverse true/false of what it's truthy value is, and then inverses it yet again to get the true/false version of the truthy value.

Comment: That is correct, the `!!` will convert the value to a boolean, but the `if` statement would be equivalent to one that does not use `!!`.

Comment: does this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: It's a way of typecasting to boolean. if value of `this._currentItemIndex` is undefined adding `!!` will evaluate it to false. If the value of `this._currentItemIndex` is `0` it will evaluate to false.

Comment: `!` negates the value, so if your `this._currentItemIndex` is true it will be false. If you use `!!` on a boolean it will always return the value since it negates it twice so:
true => false => true or false => true => false.
Mostly the `!!` is used to make sure you definetly have a boolean type.

Comment: A simple google search for "javascript double exclamation mark operator" returns quite a few articles, here are two of them: (https://medium.com/@edplatomail/js-double-bang-or-the-not-operator-part-40e55d089bf0), and (https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-bang-bang-i-shot-you-down-use-of-double-bangs-in-javascript-7c9d94446054)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'll see code like:

```
let x = !!y;
```

Where this is casting whatever value `y` has into a simple `true` or `false` outcome, a boolean. This is often employed to avoid retaining references to things you don't need, like `y` could be a complex structure but you don't care about the details, you just want to track if it was assigned.

It's unusual to see this employed in an `if` since it really doesn't do anything useful. It converts to a boolean, but `if` will anyway. This is just junk code.

It might as well be `if (!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!x)` for all the good it does.

A better version would look like:

```
if (this._currentItemIndex) {
  // Some non-zero value was assigned
}
```

Or if it is populated:

```
if (this._currentItemIndex > 0) {
  // Communicates intent better
}
```

Comment: @Icepickle In an `if`?

Comment: I can't recall ever seeing the arguments of an if typed in typescript

Comment: @Taplar I use `!!` all the time to cast to boolean, but never in an `if`. It seems like [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @tadman I'm agreeing with you, :)